# which of the following statement is true.,,,,?

Tags: general-topology

which of the following statement is true concerning topological spaces.?

1.continiuous  image of non compact space is non compact.

2.every metrizbale space is normal....

my attempts: option 1 is false,,,,as continuous image of compact set is compacts

```
             option 2 is trues  as it is given munkre topology  books
```

am I correct ?  pliz tell me

Comment: The first is false but yours' is not a proof, you must find a counterexample!

Comment: @ Giuseepe Bargagnati   i know that  continious image of compact set is compact,,,,as   i take, f :[0,1)→[0,1]  i take f(x) =  x

Comment: Hint on 1): constant functions are continuous and singletons are compact.

Comment: @ drhab  is it right f(x) = 1 ?

Comment: You could use that. Let $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by that and let $X$ be non-compact.

Comment: i take X = (0,1)  is it  right ?

Comment: If it is equipped with its usual topology then $(0,1)$ is not compact, so yes in that case.

Comment: thanks a  lot @ drhab,,,but constant function is not compact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is false. E.g. Let $X$ be any non-compact space and $Y=\{0\}.$ Let $f(p)=0$ for all $p\in X.$

(2). Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A, B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X.$ To avoid the trivial cases, suppose $A\ne \phi\ne B.$

For $a\in A$ let $d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b).$ For $b\in b$ let $d(b,A)=\inf_{a\in A}d(b,A).$

For $a\in A$ we have $d(a,B)>0$ because $a\not \in \bar B.$ For $b\in B$ we have $d(b, A)>0$ because $b\not \in \bar A.$

Let $U=\cup_{a\in A}B_d(a,\frac {1}{2}d(a,B)).$ Let $V=\cup_{b\in B}B_d(b,\frac {1}{2}d(b,A)).$

$U$ and $V$ are open sets with $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V.$

Suppose by contradiction that $c\in U\cap V.$ Take $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $d(c,a)<\frac {1}{2}d(a,B)$ and $d(c,b)<\frac {1}{2}d(b,A).$ $$\text  { Then }\quad  d(a,B)\leq d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(c,b)<\frac {1}{2}d(a,B)+\frac {1}{2}d(b,A)$$   $$ \text { and }\quad \;\; d(b,A)\leq d(b,a)\leq d(b,c)+d(c,a)<\frac {1}{2}d(b,A)+\frac {1}{2}d(a,B).$$ The sum of the two far-left terms in the above inequalities, which is $d(a,B)+d(b,A),$  is less than the sum of the two far-right terms, which is also $d(a,B)+d(b,A).$ This is absurd, so we conclude that $c$ does not exist.

That is, $U\cap V=\phi$.

A metric space is also a $T_1$ space. I will leave that to you.  So a metric space is a normal space.

Comment: thanks a lots  Daniel wainfleet